# Procedural C++ programming with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm having trouble getting the set-up and namespace to work the way I'm used to with something like Notepad++ of gVIM.

I started an "empty" c++ windows console application project in Visual Studio 2013, and have set up the following test program"

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() { 
    hello();
    return 0; 
}

void hello() { cout << "hello"; }
```

When I try anything of this form, I get the following error for every call of function declared outside of `main()`:

> error C3861:'AuxFunction': identifier not found

I don't get any other syntactical or compilation errors.

Is there something I have to change in the project properties (they're all at default except for the empty project and omission of any precompiled headers), or will I have to structure my programs differently if I use Visual Studio?

Comment: You need to declare functions before they are called. Put `void hello();` above main.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been over a decade since I used VS, but at a glance try adding a prototype for your hello function:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void hello();

int main() { 
    hello();
    return 0; 
}

void hello() { cout << "hello"; }
```

(more general programming than VS, but the error is VS-specific I guess).

Comment: Bingo. Function prototypes were optional in every GNU compiler I ever used, so I'm not in the habit of using them for extremely small programs like this one. Much thanks.

Comment: It's an easy mistake to make.  You start with a short program with the function defined before main(), then it gets a bit long, so you move it below main and it looks like VS gives you a completely obtuse error message.  :)